# setting up web sockets

Tags: javascript, websocket

When using web sockets all the tutorials I can find talk about the code for the client side. But the server side is just left out. What does the connection url here actually point too? Do I need to also be using PHP, Ruby, node.js or any server side language?

```
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://html5rocks.websocket.org/echo', ['soap', 'xmpp']);
```

Tutorial referenced:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/

Answer (score 0):

There are some server side languages that have Websockets support, I personally recommend using:

> [Socket.io](http://socket.io/)

Who works over node.js, it's very easy to setup and a good starting point. Later you can have an Websockets endpoint in any language. Java and C# solutions are a bit complicated by the time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a server that handles websockets. Many do including Apache HTTPD, Apache Tomcat, Play framework, and nodejs.

Here is an example:
http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2012/05/01/how-apache-tomcat-implemented-websocket

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the great (and simple) echo sample on [websocket.org](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html)?

Also, Kaazing has a hosted WebSocket server, and a browser-based tutorial that walks you through a simple pub-sub example.
Check out:

- [Tutorial Home Page](http://tutorial.kaazing.com/) with screencast of completed app
- [Seven-part blog post](http://blog.kaazing.com/2012/08/08/a-step-by-step-tutorial-of-building-a-simple-peer-to-peer-websocket-app-part-1/) about with step-by-step instructions
- [Completed demo in JSFiddle](http://goo.gl/uYrSGa) (with HTML and JavaScript source code)
  **Hint:** Open this link in two browser windows an interact with the slider above the image

Hope this helps!